# colored bash does not work as root user

Tags: bash, shell, colors

I have noticed that when I ssh to a server and then su to the root user, I do not get color in bash. In this specific case when I say "do not get color in bash" I am talking about editing files with vim. Now, if I sudo after login I get color, so no problems there. If I su to root and  source /root/.bash_profile then I get color as root. But I do not want to have to source .bash_profile file every time I su to root. Here are the contents of my /root/.bashrc and /root/.bash_profile files. What can I do to get color when doing su?

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be     colorized:
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "`dircolors`"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'


# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
     . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

=============================================

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
alias vi='/usr/bin/vim'
alias grep='/bin/grep --color'
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim

# HISTSIZE = number of lines in memory while session is ongoing
# HISTFILESIZE = maximum number of lines in the history file on   disk
export HISTSIZE=3000
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
export HISTFILE=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print   $1}')
```

Comment: Personal opinion: The root user should have no aliases, colours or other bells or whistles in their shell. The _very few instances_ (near to never ever) when you're in a interactive root shell, you should type out _exactly_ what you need to do, and then exit. Accidentally doing the wrong thing is fatal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `su -` to get a login shell, or move the aliases to `~/.bashrc`. See: [Answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to check my `$TERM` variable by running

```
printf "$TERM\n"
```

which I got

```
xterm
```

because I was using putty from windows, therefore I edited it in putty like so:
Connection>Data>Terminal details>Terminal-type string:
`xterm-256color`

[image]

(Also **please** make sure to **save** these settings)

Lastly you need to edit /root/.bashrc like so:

```
sudo vi /root/.bashrc
```

on lines 38-41 below:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

to be as follows (again in lines 38-41):

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|xterm-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Alternatively you can just uncomment line 46:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

by removing the #, however I chose to do the above instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
su -m
```

Works for me on a terminal su'ing into a pi.