# non color Kali Linux Terminal in root user

Tags: kali-linux

I recently install Kali Linux 2020. as you know it's a non root user by default in this version! and also as you know the terminal it's colorful for Dir or executable files and etc but when I change my user to root the Terminal is turned to black & white for all thing! do any body have a solution for this?

Comment: I wanna make the Terminal colorful as like always in the root user :|

Comment: Possibly related: [colored bash does not work as root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/colored-bash-does-not-work-as-root-user)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good link [here](https://www.tecmint.com/customize-bash-colors-terminal-prompt-linux/) that explains what all of that is doing with the PS1 line. It also lists all the colours so you can tailor it to exactly what you'd like

Below is what worked for me, and what produced a colour scheme that I find easy to work with.

As mentioned by others, open up this file from a terminal with

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and under the existing '# PS1 =' line (you can delete this line if you wish or leave it commented), add

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u@\h\e[0;0m\]:\e[0;36m\]\w\e[0;0m\]\$ '
```

That gives a decent colour difference to the root and the following directories.

*The section responsible for the formatting for this is
e[0;31m]
the 'e' begins a format, the 'm' ends it.
The '0' here is for normal font, change to 1 for bold, or 4 for underlined.
The font colour is the '31' (red in this case) - a full list of available colour codes can be found on the above link.
All other letters in here are explained in the link also if you're interested*

Then remove the comments (#) from the middle section (under '# You may uncomment the following lines if you want 'ls' to be colorized') to show colours on lists

exit and save

then run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to update the changes which you should now see in the terminal.

and you're done! :)

Comment: Simplest solution I found. Just works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, luckily it comes with an easy solution.

If you **just** want `ls` to display color, **uncommenting** some lines in the `~/.bashrc` file of the root user will be enough. You'll find what to do in it; you can access it with `vim .bashrc` right after logging into root.

If you want to see that characteristic red `root@kali:~$` at the beginning of the line too it takes some more steps but it's also pretty straightforward.

First, launch the terminal as **non root** and open `~/.bashrc` again (this is the non-root user file, the one with the color enabled) and locate the comment that says:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
```

Now copy all the code below until you reach:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
```

We don't need whats below this last line, it is already in root's `.bashrc` (the lines we uncommented before).

Now log into root, do `vim .bashrc` once more and **paste** the same code somwhere in the file. Relaunch the terminal and it's done. At least it worked for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code in a text editor in Kali or anywhere and save as `.bashrc`. Then open the file browser in Kali. In the options, toggle on "hidden files" and then paste the `.bashrc` file and click on replace and you are done.

Just restart your system once. (I didn't have to restart, it might work for you, too.) Let me know if it works for you.

Code:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m      \]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a user that has a terminal with colors, you can just copy that users `~/.bashrc` to the root home directory and then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

while logged in as root, and it should give you the same colors as the user had.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some things and this is a better and shorter solution.

To have color in the prompt, from user root edit the next file

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add this line in the file

```bsh
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h:\W\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Comment out some lines  to have color in the command `ls` just like the file suggests (please follow the described instructions inside the file)

Save changes and reload the file with this command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

P.S. To change a custom color of the prompt you can use the numbers in the following table, you need to change the numbers in this part (`[\e[1;32m\]`)

```
Negro       0;30     Gris Oscuro   1;30
Azul        0;34     Azul Claro    1;34
Verde       0;32     Verde Claro   1;32
Cyan        0;36     Cyan Claro    1;36
Rojo        0;31     Rojo Claro    1;31
Púrpura     0;35     Fucsia        1;35
Café        0;33     Amarillo      1;33
Gris Claro  0;37     Blanco        1;37
```